# Styles messed up in local copy of web app only - IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I recently upgrade to IE8 (because I'm living on the cutting edge) and found the styles in at least 2 web applications are rendering incorrectly, but only in their local copies. The deployed/remote versions of the apps (on dev, test, prod servers) still render correctly in my IE8. I'm lost as to what the difference could be. Is IIS 7 somehow better at serving up style sheets than IIS 6? 7 being the version on the servers

Comment: You need to capture the requests. Double check whether the two requests send the same request and receive the same response.
If there is no difference, the problem is not an IIS issue.

Comment: Just out of interest, why not go all the way to IE10? IE8 is really being phased out pretty quickly.

Comment: `I recently upgrade to IE8 (because I'm living on the cutting edge)`, I hope this is intended as a sarcasm. Some code will be helpful.

Comment: Compatibility. IE10 means no more xp and upgrading from xp is a bigger effort that I cant do on a whim myself in 10 mins.

Comment: And as for code, short of pasting 4 style sheets, a master page and an aspx page, I'm not sure what to give you. If I could narrow it down to a reasonable block of code, I would, but it's identical code behaving different depending on where it's coming from, so I'm not sure it has anything to do with code. Unless you meant IE8's code

Comment: Is everyone seeing no code and assuming that's an oversight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 (and later versions) have a feature called "Compatibility mode", which is intended to make the browser work like IE7.

I suspect that this is what you are seeing. You can prove this by pressing F12 to get IE's Developer Tools window. In the top-right corner of this window it will show you the browser mode. If it says "Compatibility mode" then you've found the problem ("Quirks mode" would also be a problem, but I don't think it matches the described symptoms).

The reason I suspect this is the problem is because of the way you describe the same site working fine when deployed remotely but going wrong on your local system.

This is a fairly common issue and is caused by an obscure config setting in IE that tells it to use compatibility mode by default on local intranet sites. For reasons known only to Microsoft, they chose to make this flag default to being switched on.

The solution to this problem is therefore to switch this flag off. Go to the Tools menu, and find the Compatibility View Settings option. This will bring up a window with some checkboxes that you should un-tick. Your browser should now behave itself on local sites.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Interesting. That's exactly the problem. Thank you